# using of model into controller in a simple mvc

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model

I use [this mvc](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html). Now I want to know how can I use of the data of model into controller ?

here is a line of code:

```
$registry->db = db::getInstance();
```

but the above code is not working on the controller, I can use `db::getInstance();` in the controller directly. but I can not use $registry->db instead of it. why ?

finally, how can I use of model into controller ?

Answer (score 0):

All properties to $registry are set to private, so you'll have to store it somewhere else:

```
$db = db::getInstance();
```